# aps.net não chama javascript no code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

gostaria de chamar de meu código uma função em javascript que encontra-se no meu html. Segue abaixo meus códigos

**HTML**

---

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="webReport0800net.login" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Relatórios CSC - Login</title>
        <script src="js/dhtmlx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="css/dhtmlx.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/roboto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function ValidaUsuario() {
                if (document.getElementById("<%=usuTextBox.ClientID%>").value == "") {
                    dhtmlx.message(
                        { type: "error", text: "Login inválido! Favor informar seu ID GR" }
                    )
                    //alert("Informe o nome.");
                    document.getElementById("<%=usuTextBox.ClientID%>").focus();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    //REGEX para aceitar apens texto no formado dos IDs da GRSA
                    var ck_id1 = /^[Ff]{1}[Ee]{1}[Gg]{1}[Rr]{1}\d{4}$/;
                    var ck_id2 = /^[Gg]{1}[Rr]{1}\d{6}$/;
                    var tempNome = document.getElementById("<%=usuTextBox.ClientID%>").value;
                    var matchNome1 = tempNome.match(ck_id1);
                    var matchNome2 = tempNome.match(ck_id2);
                    if (matchNome1 == null && matchNome2 == null) {
                        dhtmlx.message(
                            { type: "error", text: "ID informado é inválido! Favor informar seu ID GR" }
                        )
                        document.getElementById("<%=usuTextBox.ClientID %>").focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (document.getElementById("<%=senhaTextBox.ClientID%>").value == "") {
                            dhtmlx.message(
                                { type: "error", text: "Favor digitar a sua senha de rede!" }
                            )
                            document.getElementById("<%=senhaTextBox.ClientID%>").focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                function Erro() {
                    dhtmlx.message(
                                { type: "error", text: "Usuário e/ou senha incorretos!!" }
                            )
                }
                return true;
            }

        </script>    
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                background-color: #bea879
            }
             .div_p
            {
                position:absolute;
                top:13%;
                left:35%;
                background-color: #eeece0;
                width: 350px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
                -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
                -box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
                -moz-border-radius:15px;
                -box-border-radius:15px;
                -webkit-border-radius:15px;
                 border-radius:15px;

            }
            .div_logo_gr
            {
               position:relative;
               padding-top:5%;
               padding-left:28%;
            }
            .div_text
            {
                text-align:center;
                color:Blue;
            }
            .div_form_login
            {
               position:relative;
               padding-top:5%;
               padding-left:30%;
            }
            .modal_loader
            {
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 999;
                padding-top: 15px;
                background-color:Transparent;
                filter: alpha(opacity=60);
                opacity: 0.6;
                -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            }
            .div_logo_csc
            {
               position:relative;
               padding-left:33%;
               padding-bottom:5%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=div_p>
            <div class=div_logo_gr>
                <img src="img/logo-gr-compass.jpg" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class=div_text>
                Relatórios gerenciais CSC. Acesso ao sistema
            </div>
            <div class=div_text>
                Use seu ID e senha de rede para o acesso
            </div>
            <div class=div_form_login>
                <form id="login" runat="server">
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="loginFormScriptManager" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
                    </asp:ScriptManager>
                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="loginFormUpdateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="loginFormUpdatePanel">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                            <div class=modal_loader>
                                <div class="center">
                                    <img alt="" src="img/loader.gif" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                    <div>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="loginFormUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div>
                                    <b>Login</b>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="usuTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div style="margin-top:7px;">
                                    <b>Senha</b>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="senhaTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div style="margin-top:7px;">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="lembrarUsuarioCheckBox" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                                        Text="Lembrar Usuário / Senha" />
                                </div>
                                <div style="margin-top:7px;">
                                        <asp:Button ID="validaButton" runat="server" Text="Acessar" 
                                            OnClientClick=" return ValidaUsuario()" onclick="validaButton_Click" />
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>


                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class=div_logo_csc>
                <img src="img/logo_csc.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Net;

namespace webReport0800net
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        string retornoLogon;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                usuTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                senhaTextBox.Text = string.Empty;

            }
        }

        protected void validaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string adPath = "LDAP://DC=gr,DC=sa"; //Path to your LDAP directory server
            LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);
            try
            {
                retornoLogon = adAuth.IsAuthenticated("gr.sa", usuTextBox.Text, senhaTextBox.Text);
                if(!retornoLogon.Contains("Ocorreu") || !retornoLogon.Contains("Erro"))
                {
                    string groups = adAuth.GetGroups();

                    //Create the ticket, and add the groups.
                    bool isCookiePersistent = lembrarUsuarioCheckBox.Checked;
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                              usuTextBox.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), isCookiePersistent, groups);

                    //Encrypt the ticket.
                    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

                    //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
                    HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

                    if (true == isCookiePersistent)
                        authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;

                    //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
                    Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

                    //You can redirect now.
                    if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(usuTextBox.Text, false));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        //PerfilClass.MyLogin = usuTextBox.Text.ToString().ToUpper();
                        //PerfilClass.MyNome = retornoLogon.ToString().ToUpper();
                        //PerfilClass.MyHost = Environment.MachineName.ToString().ToUpper();
                        //foreach (var item in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName))
                        //{
                        //    if (item.ToString().Substring(0,3) == "172")
                        //    {
                        //        PerfilClass.MyIP = item.ToString();
                        //        break;
                        //    }
                        //}
                        //Response.Redirect("~/menu.aspx");
                        return;
                    } 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Já tentei todas linhas abaixo mas não funciona.
                //Quando debugo as linhas são interpretadas sem error
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "UpdateMsg", "$(document).ready(function(){EnableControls();alert('Overrides successfully Updated.');DisableControls();});", true);
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "mensagem", "Erro()", true);
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "showmessagebox", "Erro();", true);
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Erro", "Erro();", true);

            }
        }
    }
}
```